# Adding a constant value to intermediate layers of cnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to add a constant matrix to output layer of intermediate layer in cnn during learning and then send it to next layer. I put my code here and use Add functions but it produce error. what should I do? using Add is a true solution or not?

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
import numpy as np

w_main = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4,1))
w_main=w_main.astype(np.float32)
w_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28,1),dtype='float32')
w_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_main
w_expand.reshape(1,28,28,1)
#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)

encoder=Model(inputs=image, outputs=encoded)
encoder.summary()
#-----------------------adding w---------------------------------------
encoded_merged=Kr.layers.Add(encoded,w_expand)

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#encoded_merged = Input((28, 28, 2))
x = Conv2D(2, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded_merged)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(x) 

decoder=Model(inputs=encoded_merged, outputs=decoded)
decoder.summary()
```

the produced error is:

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
>   I am in a hurry. please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the layer in the wrong way, this is the correct way:

```
encoded_merged=Kr.layers.Add()([encoded,w_expand])
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your constant into a Layer that will return a tensor, currently you have `numpy` array which cannot be added to a tensor:

```
add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + Kr.backend.constant(w_expand))
```

And use it with the layer you want to add it to:

```
encoded_merged = add_const(encoded)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So, each time I need to add some constant things to a tensor first I should wrap them to a layer that it will do with lambda?
could you please recommend me a link that explains these concepts completely?

Comment: You can check the [documentation on Lambda layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/).

Comment: I change the code based on the thing that you said but after implementation it produces this error
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_8:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "input_8". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Comment: I only chang these lines of code
1) add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + Kr.backend.constant(w_expand))
2) encoded_merged = add_const(encoded)
3) encoder=Model(inputs=image, outputs=encoded_merged)
4) deconv1 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same' (encoded_merged)
 5) decoder=Model(inputs=encoded_merged, outputs=decoded)
model=Model(inputs=image,outputs=decoded)

Comment: I also want to know when I want to use fit function I should send w_expand as an input or it will add during learning? I used the following code. does it consider w_expand during learning and add it to encoder or not?
model.fit([x_train], [x_train],
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=64, 
          validation_data=([x_validation], [x_validation]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='C:/tmp/autoencoder', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False)])

Comment: The model construction includes the constant, so you don't need to add the constant. But you can't just save and load model, you will need to `load_weights` and construct the model programmatically every time. Another option might be to give constant as `Input` like the image.

Comment: sorry for my questions, I am a beginner and I do not know some things correctly. you said the second option is to give constant as input. could you please tell me how can I do it and where should I add it?

Comment: sorry, no one can explain me?

Comment: I meant, `constant = Input(...)` and use it as `...=Add()([encoded, constant])`, have a look at the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, but I meant, if I want to reconstruct this constant too and see the function of the network on reconstructing it, should I send it as input to fit function like this:
watermark_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=4,
          batch_size=128, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wt_expand], [x_validation,wt_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='C:/tmp/autoencoder', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False)])
or I can do this without sending w_expand to fit function?

Comment: please answer me. I really need your help.

Comment: I add this wtm=Input((28,28,1))
and then use encoded_merged=Kr.layers.Add()([encoded,wtm]) but when I want to make my model encoder=Model(inputs=image, outputs= encoded_merged)
it produce this error
Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "input_3". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_4', 'convl1e', 'convl2e', 'convl3e', 'dropout_3', 'reconstructed_I']
what is the problem?